# Como fazer uma disjunção total em diagrama EER? (MySQL Worckbench)

Tags: sql, script, mysql

Olá, preciso entregar um sistema de venda e preciso fazer com que a entidade "forma de pagamento" seja uma dessas sub classes (cartao, cheque, boleto ou deposito), somente uma por instância... Como representar o relacionamento no diagrama EER?

Da forma que está na imagem está errado, pois toda instância de "forma de pagamento" terá as chaves estrangeiras de todas as sub-entidades, mesmo colocando para ser DEFAULT NULL estará de certa forma errada, como prosseguir?

[image: Preciso fazer com que a entidade "forma de pagamento" seja uma dessas sub classes (Cartao, cheque, boleto ou deposito), somente uma por instância... Como representar o relacionamento no diagrama EER?]

Comment: não faça essas tabelas para os tipos de condições de pagamentos, a maioria das colunas se repetem, e se surgir uma nova condição, terá que criar outra tabela ?! deixe o tipo apenas como uma coluna dentro da condição... dependendo da condição umas colunas serão utilizadas, outras não, mas não há problema

Answer (score -1):

Normaliza a entidade de pagamento.

Cria uma tabela única de pagamento com os campos necessários e cria também uma tabela de Tipo de Pagamento. Depois adiciona uma Fk na tabela de pagamento.

Dessa forma você só irá ter duas tabelas para todos os tipos de pagamento